# How to fix the 'variable' was not declared in this scope error?

Tags: c++

**this code shows error 'len' and 'wid' was not declared in this scope
how can I fix it?**

```
class Shape {    
    private:    
        double length;    
        double width;    
    public:  

        Shape(double len, double wid) {  
            length = len;  
            width = wid;  
        }

        double getArea() {   
            return len*wid;    
        }    
};    


int main() {    
    Shape Shape(2,4);    
    cout << Shape.getArea();    
}
```

Comment: Indent your code correctly, it's easier to check your functions bounds that way.

Comment: In the `getArea` method, use the local variables instead, i.e., `length` and `width`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `getArea()` function should return `length*width`.

`len` and `wid` are the local variables defined in the constructor whereas `length` and `width` are class variables which can be accessed by other functions. So `len` and `wid` go out of scope when the definition of the constructor ends.

Answer (score 1):

you should return `length*width` .